# How to extract a complex value in JsonPathExtractor

Tags: json, groovy, jmeter, performance-testing, json-path-expression

Below is the returned sample json

```
[
"id":
[
    {
        "reports":
            [
                {
                    "metadata":
                        {
                            "materialName" : "materialName1"
                            "materialType" : "materialType1"    
                        },
                        "xvalue": null,
                        "yvalue": null,
                },
                {
                    "metadata":
                        {
                            "materialName" : "materialName2"
                            "materialType" : "materialType2"    
                        },
                        "xvalue": null,
                        "yvalue": null,
                },
            ],
            "someValue" : "someValue1"
            "id" : "id1"
    },
    "reports":
            [
                {
                    "metadata":
                        {
                            "materialName" : "materialName3"
                            "materialType" : "materialType3"    
                        },
                        "xvalue": null,
                        "yvalue": null,
                },
                {
                    "metadata":
                        {
                            "materialName" : "materialName4"
                            "materialType" : "materialType4"    
                        },
                        "xvalue": null,
                        "yvalue": null,
                },
            ],
            "someValue" : "someValue1"
            "id" : "id2"
  ]
```

]

I have below Json expression in Json Path Extractor in JMeter

```
$.data[0].materials[?(@.id)].reports[*].metadata['materialName','materialType']
```

The above expression returned as below for every 'id' in a json array

```
materialName1, materialType1

materialName2, materialType2

materialName3, materialType3

materialName4, materialType4
```

but I want to extract the value of 'id' along with 'materialName' and 'materialType' as mentioned below

```
id1, materialName1, materialType1

id1, materialName2, materialType2

id2, materialName3, materialType3

id2, materialName4, materialType4
```

etc.

please help me on this.

Thanks,
Jatin

Answer (score 0):

Add JSR223 sampler and log it directly with:

```
log.info(variable)
```

Variables can be resolved in any sampler comment section with **${variable}** for testing purposes.

[image]

Comment: I want to fetch id along with materialName and material type using the mentioned Json expression. Currenlty I dont get an idea that how to fetch as I am only getting materialname and materialtype for each id but I want id to be returned as  well

Comment: You can have more than one extractor if you need to get more values from json. Its hard to answer without seeing json.

Comment: Added a sample json for your reference

Comment: Yes I know that I can have multiple extractors but tell how it will give a combination of all the subid's for every id in the response. Like I have asked in modified comment. Please dont tell me that json I mention is incorrect as it is just for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter provides [__logn()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__logn) function allowing printing whatever you want to [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

Also in case of > 1 matches returned by JSON Extractor JMeter generates the following [variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

```
var_1=foo
var_2=bar
...
var_matchNr=2
```

so you will be able to print them to jmeter.log file as:

```
1.upto(vars.get('var_matchNr') as int, { index ->
    log.info(vars.get('var_' + index))
})
```

if you want to print to [STDOUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)) instead - replace `log.info` with `println`

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: I have updated my question to better explain what I wanted. Please check

Comment: what you posted is not a valid json hence you won't be able to parse it with JSON Extractor

Comment: It's easy given you [ask a good question and provide minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), I'm not going to waste my time trying to restore the correct valid JSON out of the stuff you provided